# DropShadowEffect to a specific element in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, effect

I have a **Border** that consist of other UI Controls like Canvas, Buttons, ComboBox etc. I only want a **DropShadowEffect** on the Border, but all children Controls end up inheriting the **DropShadowEffect**.

For example, the following code produce **DropShadowEffect** on the TextBox, Button, ComboBox.
How to I apply **DropShadowEffect** ONLY to the border?

```
<Border>
   <Border.Effect>
      <DropShadowEffect ...>
   </Border.Effect>
   <Canvas>
      <TextBox>...</TextBox>
      <Button>...</Button>
      <ComboBox>...<ComboBox>
   </Canvas>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a `DropShadowEffect` is applied to a `layout container`, such as DockPanel or Canvas, the effect is applied to the visual tree of the element or visual, including all of its child elements.

But following article shows a workaround to achieve this goal [here](http://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/bitmap-effects-in-wpf-part-ii/).

Let’s say you have the Border with effect. Just have `another border with same position but without the effect`, that would resolve the problem -

```
<Border Margin="10">
   <Border.Effect>
      <DropShadowEffect ...>
   </Border.Effect>
</Border>
<Border Margin="10">
   <Canvas>
      <TextBox>...</TextBox>
      <Button>...</Button>
      <ComboBox>...<ComboBox>
   </Canvas>
</Border>
```

Comment: nice trick suggestion, but it doesn't work. In addition, I also add a white/transparent border to the second border, but still inheriting the first border effect. Strange...

Answer (score 2):

Bit tricky, I did it like this.

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="ShadowBorderShadowTemplate">
        <!-- Start shadow effect to fragment -->
        <Grid x:Name="Transform">
            <Border BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="Gray"
                Background="{x:Null}"
                Margin="1">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="6"
              Direction="270"
              ShadowDepth="2" />
                </Border.Effect>
            </Border>

            <Border BorderThickness="0"
                    Margin="1,2,1,1"
                    BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                    Background="White" />
        </Grid>
        <!-- End shadow effect to fragment -->
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ContentControlTemplateWithShadow" 
               TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Grid>
            <!-- Shadow around the left nav -->
            <ContentControl Template="{DynamicResource ShadowBorderShadowTemplate}" />
            <ContentPresenter />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

and use the resources like

```
 <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource ContentControlTemplateWithShadow}">
        <Border>
            <Canvas>
                <TextBox Text="ABCD" Canvas.Left="115" Canvas.Top="134" />
                <Button Canvas.Left="115" Canvas.Top="91">Test</Button>
                <ComboBox Canvas.Left="115" Canvas.Top="54" />
            </Canvas>
        </Border>
    </ContentControl>
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: thanks, though it seems like it's easier to do it in code behind than XAML

Comment: may be but what if we need to apply shadow at multiple places?